# something wrong with the result of mysql query with joins and select

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Good day,

I am trying to join 3 tables for my inventory report but I am getting weird results out of it.

my query

```
SELECT i_inventory.xid,
       count(x_transaction_details.xitem) AS occurrence,
       i_inventory.xitem AS itemName,
       SUM(i_items_group.or_qty) AS `openingQty`,
       avg(x_transaction_details.cost) AS avg_cost,
       SUM(x_transaction_details.qty) AS totalNumberSold,
       SUM(i_items_group.or_qty) - SUM(x_transaction_details.qty) AS totalRemQty
FROM x_transaction_details
LEFT JOIN i_inventory ON x_transaction_details.xitem = i_inventory.xid
LEFT JOIN i_items_group ON i_inventory.xid = i_items_group.xitem
WHERE (x_transaction_details.date_at BETWEEN '2015-01-18 03:14:54' AND '2015-10-18 03:14:54')
  AND i_inventory.xid = 3840
GROUP BY x_transaction_details.xitem
ORDER BY occurrence DESC
```

This query gives me this result:
[image]

See the `openingQty` column, I then tried to do a simple query to verify the result,

here's my query for checking the openingQty with joining only 2 tables `i_items_group` table (batches are stored) and `i_inventory` table (item Information are stored).

```
SELECT i_inventory.xid,
       i_inventory.xitem,
       SUM(i_items_group.or_qty) AS openingQty,
       i_items_group.cost
FROM i_inventory
INNER JOIN i_items_group ON i_inventory.xid = i_items_group.xitem
WHERE i_inventory.xid = 3840
  AND (i_items_group.date_at BETWEEN '2015-01-18 03:14:54' AND '2015-10-18 03:14:54')
```

my result was:

[image]

which is the correct data.

I also made a query on my `x_transaction_details` table also to verify if its correct or not.

heres my query:

```
select xitem, qty as qtySold from x_transaction_details where xitem = 3840 
AND (date_at BETWEEN '2015-01-18 03:14:54' AND '2015-10-18 03:14:54')
```

result:

[image]

Which would total to: 15-quatitySold.

I'm just confused on how did I get 3269 as a result of my query where as the true openingQty should be only 467.

I guess the problem was in my query with joins, its messing up with number of transactions then it sums it up (I really dont know though).

Can you please help me identify it, and help me come up with the correct query.

Comment: it would help if you could set up a fiddle for the problem

Comment: Ok @vkp I'll try to do that.. I dont know how to do it though xD like how to create a table..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem with multiple SUM statements in a single query. Keep in mind how SQL does aggregation: first it generates a set of data that is not aggregated, then it aggregates it. Try your query without the GROUP BY or aggregate functions, and you'll be surprised what you turn up. There aren't enough of the right details in your post for me to determine where the breakdown is, but I can guess.

It looks like you have an xitem corresponding to some kind of product, then you have joined that to both transactions and items groups. Suppose a particular xitem matches with 3 transactions and 5 item groups. You'll get 15 records from that join. And when you sum it, any SUM calculations based on fields from the transaction table will be 5x higher than you expect, and any SUM calculations from the item groups table will be 3x higher than you expect. The key symptom here is the aggregate result being a multiple of the correct value, but seemingly different multiples for different rows.

There are multiple ways to address this kind of error. Some developers like to calculate one of hte aggregates in a subquery, then do the other aggregate in the main query and group by the already correct result from the subquery. Others like to write in-line queries to do the aggregate right in the expression:

```
SELECT xitem, (SELECT SUM(i_items_group.or_qty) FROM i_items_group WHERE i_inventory.xid = i_items_group.xitem) AS `openingQty`
, -- select more fields
```

Find what approach works best for you. But if you want to see the evidence for yourself, run this query with the aggregates gone and you'll see why those SUMs are doing what they are doing:

```
SELECT i_inventory.xid,
       x_transaction_details.xitem AS occurrence,
       i_inventory.xitem AS itemName,
       i_items_group.or_qty,
       x_transaction_details.cost,
       x_transaction_details.qty,
       i_items_group.or_qty - x_transaction_details.qty AS RemainingQty
FROM x_transaction_details
LEFT JOIN i_inventory ON x_transaction_details.xitem = i_inventory.xid
LEFT JOIN i_items_group ON i_inventory.xid = i_items_group.xitem
WHERE (x_transaction_details.date_at BETWEEN '2015-01-18 03:14:54' AND '2015-10-18 03:14:54')
  AND i_inventory.xid = 3840

ORDER BY occurrence DESC
```

Comment: Your absolutely correct sir @theTTGGuy... I tried creating a fiddle as well but its seems to complex since i have so many columns in each table.. I also have researched something like this problem and now my I am just studying on how am I going to apply it on my own query.. Thanks alot for the detailed answer sir.. it helped me understand the problem and had more search keys to used :)